# how to upgrade my ros to latest version

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ros(electric), old version ,I know, so I wanna upgrade to ros(hydro), Is there a simple way.
I have google a lot, can't find a good answer.(ps. I am in Ubuntu 11.10)
Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98881/how-to-upgrade-my-ros-to-latest-version/) by [Yum.my](https://answers.ros.org/users/2780/yum.my/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not a simple way to upgrade to use hydro on Ubuntu 11.10.  hydro is only supported on precise, quantal, and raring (12.04, 12.10, and 13.04)

Target platforms are designated in REP 3: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0